# changing teamcity agent npm version

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to point teamcity to use the latest npm version **6.0.1**. but for some reason, it is stuck using **5.6.0**.

**node.js 10.1.0**

**node.js.npm 5.6.0**

the node version gets updated.

I have tried adding npm i npm@latest -g to the build step, it runs successfully, but the teamcity agent version doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, i change the Teamcity server and agent services users from Local System to an actual User.

Login into the build server as the user and Installed npm and node. Did a server restart.

Now TC using the latest version of npm.

Answer (score 1):

You must first find out where node & npm are installed *at the system level*.  Using *the usual way to upgrade* `npm i npm@latest -g` will install npm into your user profile, it won't update that system-level installation (which is what TeamCity's build agent uses).

On my (Windows) build agent I found it at C:\nodejs but your box may vary

Open a command prompt, `cd` to that directory and then use `npm i npm@latest` (note no `-g` switch). This will upgrade your system-level npm installation (used by the build agent).  You will likely need administrative rights to the box etc etc.